# Cannot upload PDFs or DOC's.

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is form's type etc

```
<?php
echo form_open_multipart("/Register/registerformModel",array("name"=>"subform2","id"=>"subform2"));
?>
```

input type

```
<input name="profile" id="profile" type="file" class="input"/>
```

function

```
 $this->load->library('upload');   
 $config['upload_path'] = $this->config->item('upload_url_path').'images/member/';
 $config['allowed_types'] = 'pdf|doc';
 $config['max_size']    = '0';
 $config['profile_name'] = date('Ymd_his_').rand(10,99).rand(10,99).rand(10,99);
 $this->load->library('upload', $config);
 if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('profile'))
 {
 $data['upload_data']['profile_name'] = '';
 echo $this->upload->display_errors('<p style="color:#FF0000;">','</p>');                   
 }
 else
 {
 $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data('profile'));
 }
 $data['query'] = array(
        'profile' => $data['upload_data']['profile_name']
        );  
        $this->session->set_userdata($data['query']);
        $num = $this->common_model->insert('member',$data['query']);
```

PDF/DOC cannot be uploaded with this code? Can anybody help me??

Comment: What was the problem? did you geting any errors?

Comment: empty query, no pdf/doc uploaded.
no error shows.

Comment: Is that the entirety of your function? There are no redirects moving you away from the page before the error can be displayed? Try putting a `die();` call after your `echo $this->upload->display_errors('<p style="color:#FF0000;">','</p>');  `

Comment: yes, this is my entire function.
when query successfully run, after that page will be redirect.

Comment: I am assuming it is being successfully run? If that is the case you will never see your error message from the upload class as the page will redirect before it has a chance to echo it. Also, whats the `profile_name` config used for? Are you extending the upload class?

Comment: i am uploaded a text file and this error is occur.
"The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed".

Comment: you haven't permitted txt files in the config  `$config['allowed_types'] = 'pdf|doc|txt';`

Comment: i am changed it.
now the code is
$config['allowed_types'] = 'pdf|doc|txt';
but the error is remain same.
"The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed."

Comment: when i am uploaded the "pdf" file, that time same error is occur.
"The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed."

Comment: It could be a mime type issue. It has happened to me when I was uploading a png file and its mime type was actually jpg. Try checking the mime type of the file.

Comment: with the help of this website "http://mime.ritey.com/" i am checkout the mime type. it shows "application/octet-stream".
how can i upload this file???